# save a filename into a specific folder

Tags: c++, ofstream

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){


int value=0;

for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    ofstream myfile("Etc/filename");
    string filename ="key" + i +".txt";
    myfile<<value<<endl;

}
myfile.close();
}
```

how can i save the file under an etc folder, which has a key1.txt,key2.txt,key3.txt,key4.txt? 
it seems that i have a problem with ofstream myfile...

Anyone can enlighten of how can i change with it? Thanks!

Comment: `string filename` is never used...

Comment: @parrowdice it seems to be a problem with, ofstream myfile("folder/"+filename);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either pass a correctly formed string as argument to the constructor. For example,

```
std::ofstream myfile("key" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
```

or

```
#include <sstream> // for std::ostringstream

std::ostringstream strm;
strm << "key" << i << ".txt";
std::ofstream myfile(strm.str());
```

The above assumes you have a compiler supporting C++11. If you don't, this a slight variation on the second example would work:

```
std::ofstream myfile(strm.str().c_str());
                                ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is C++11.  But even in C++11, I think I'd use `std::ostringstream` for this.  It just seems more natural.  _Or_ I'd just use a single statement: `std::ofstream myfile( "key" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt" );`.  But typically, you'll want some additional formatting, at least if the numbers become bigger; which means `std::ostringstream`.  (I've done this a number of times, but I've always needed to use `std::setw` and set the fill character to `'0'`, to ensure that the filenames sorted correctly.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree. I was in the process adding a stringstream version. I will shorten the C++11 version too.